# Visual Studio 2010 Premium missing "Transact-SQL Editor" from Data menu

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have the Premium Edition of VS2010, I seem to be missing the "Transact-SQL Editor" editor option on the Data menu.

as per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833151.aspx)

Should it be available? If so, how can I restore it?

Comment: You tried all these way? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833212.aspx

Comment: There are two ways I can create/start the the Transact-SQL editor. 1,right click on the server in the SERVER EXPLORER, and even then I cant save it...2, File new, SQL File, but then I cant connect it to a server!

Comment: You tried the second way described in the above link?

Comment: "New Query Button"? - there is no new query button!

Comment: Updating the "NuGet" tools , seem to have bought "Transact.." menu group back to the Data Menu, but now, the SQL Query template is missing from new!!. Going to try the /instavstemplates command line option

Comment: hmmm can now add via the Data menu...I can save etc, I cant add a sql query to a C# project directly, I can do it via show all files include. But when I try File Add, the SQL template does not appear...

Comment: The dialog box for the 'Add Item' context menu item does not allow me to add a SQL script too. But the File -> New -> File... dialog does.

Answer (score 0):

I think removing the extensions, fixed it, I dont think it was a conflict, just that the removal process cleaned something up.